# Drawn graphics flicker and then disappear when resizing window

Tags: java, swing, graphics2d

The goal here is that I can click a color and shape, then two points on the figuresPanel. That colored shape is filled in on the figuresPanel, and I can add shapes on top of each other etc. I also need the current date to be displayed in the corner of the figuresPanel, on top of all the painted shapes. I am able to create shapes (though they always cover the date) no problem, but whenever I resize or minimize the window, all the painted shapes disappear. I've tried implementing quite a few different methods from Graphics (update, paint, redraw, etc.) and haven't found one that corrects this issue. I thought paintComponent() would take care of all that, but apparently not. Feel free to point out anything that could be implemented in a better way, always happy to learn something new.

```
        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            drawFigures();
            figuresPanel.add(dateLabel, c);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return (new Dimension(800, 600));
        }

        private void addFigure(Figure figure) {
            figureList.add(figure);
            listArea.append(figure.toString() + "\n");
            figure.fill(getGraphics());
        }

        private void drawFigures() {
            for (Figure f : figureList) {
                f.fill(getGraphics());
            }
        }
```

Comment: `getGraphics()` is a bad idea. Have a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details about how painting works in Swing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest a few things that might help you.

1. In your method `drawFigures()` instead of using `getGraphics()`, why don't you pass the instance of `Graphics` in `paintComponentMethod` as a parameter to the method and use it to draw the object. This will make sure that you are drawing on the same instance of the `Graphics` that you are using to paint.
2. In your method `addFigure(Figure figure)` I would suggest you remove the line `figure.fill(getGraphics());`, to draw the object completely. Instead in your `mouseClicked(MouseEvent event)` method after your `switch` statement insert:

   ```
   revalidate();
   repaint();
   ```

   This should actually take care of the drawing of the objects are done exactly on the same `Graphics` object that is being used to display the components.

I hope that this shall be helpful.

Comment: Thanks, I'm starting to understand this quite a bit more now. Appreciate the help!